# LibGDX - InputProcessor - if user draggs finger from button which represents moving on X, to button which represents moving on Y

Tags: android, libgdx, touch, draggable

So, i am creating a joystic for a android game, so in my Touching class(implementing InputProcessor) it looks like a :

```
public class Touching implements InputProcessor{

    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;

    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        x = Gdx.input.getX();
        y = Gdx.input.getY();

    if (x > 122 && x < 202 && y > 620 && y < 700 )
    {
        Core.player1.anmov(2); //button 1
    }

    if ( x > 122 && x < 202 && y > 520 && y < 600)
    {
        Core.player1.anmov(1); //button 2
    }

    if (x > 20 && x < 100 && y > 620 && y < 700)
    {
        Core.player1.anmov(3); //button 3
    }

    if (x > 222 && x < 302 && y > 620 && y < 700)
    {
        Core.player1.anmov(4); // button 4
    }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {


        x = Gdx.input.getX();
        y = Gdx.input.getY();
        if (x > 122 && x < 202 && y > 620 && y < 700)
        {
            Core.player1.anmov(7); // button 1
        }

        if ( x > 122 && x < 202 && y > 520 && y < 600)
        {
            Core.player1.anmov(8); // button 2
        }

        if (x > 20 && x < 100 && y > 620 && y < 700)
        {
            Core.player1.anmov(5); // button 3
        }

        if (x > 222 && x < 302 && y > 620 && y < 700)
        {
            Core.player1.anmov(6); // button 4
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
x = Gdx.input.getX();
y = Gdx.input.getY();

        return true;
    }
```

so now, if i touch the button which represents moving on X, dragg to button which represents moving on Y, it is still moving on X, until i get my finger out of screen(the touchUP is calling), and then, it it standing, it does not move on Y..

Can anybody help me please? I think this is a very primitive, but i cant find a solution.

Comment: This is a bad way to do what you want...

Comment: @BoldijarPaul That is a bad way to comment on a question. Try to be constructive.

Comment: @BoldijarPaul is right though, you do not need a separate class to handle simple things like you want. I would just program movement inside the player class. Even worse is the way you handle the movement itself with a global player field.

Comment: @MennoGouw I didn't gave him rate down or something, that is just the problem, he is trying to do something on the wrong way. There are like 1000 ways to do it..yea maybe I should have told him an ideea..but I don't know how good is his programming knowledge..

Comment: @BoldijarPaul just saying "This is bad" is useless, not helping anyone and just littering the question. I would say this user is between absolute beginner and beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go for something like this in the player class update method itself

```
//Declare velocity on top so you just have to change this to fine tune speed.
float velocity = 10;

if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) //isTouched should register as long as a screen is touched, you can use pointers for multiple fingers.
{
    if (touch within button) //just use Gdx.input.getX / Gdx.input.getY
    {
        position.X += velocity * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    {
     //do for each button
}
```

Never used dragging for onscreen buttons myself but theoretically this should work since `isTouched` registers as long screen is touched. `Gdx.input.getX/Y` should update. You probably had something in there that only ran once and continued moving your player until a release was registered.